# Geoposition.CivicAddress gives wrong result

Tags: windows, geolocation, microsoft-metro

I am using **Geolocator** class to get the location info for Windows Metro app.

The app gives proper result for Geo Position (Lat-Long) but gives wrong result for CivicAddress.

For example: I am in Ahmedabad, India.

The application is giving 23.033 & 72.616 as latitude & longitude which is correct but for Civic address it is giving "US" as country, while another fields for civic address (like City, Postcode & State) are empty.

Please let me know what should I do to resolve the problem.

Thanks,
Kavit.

Answer (score 0):

If there is not Civic Address provider installed, the API returns the country set by the user.

From http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/windows.devices.geolocation.civicaddress.aspx :

> ### Remarks
>
> Civic address data is not available unless a Civic Address provider has been installed. A Civic Address provider is not installed with Windows 8. If no Civic Address provider is installed, the API returns the country set by the user in the Control Panel.